# Need help getting local image to appear using Framer Motion and NEXTjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I am using NEXTJS and framer motion but the local image is not appearing on the web page. Instead I get that little clip art thing.Below is my code to the particular component not working:

```
import React from 'react'
import {motion} from "framer-motion";
import aboutPic from './images/wed.jpg'

type Props = {}

function About({}: Props) {
  return (
    <div className=" flex flex-col relative h-screen text-center md:text-left md:flex-row max- 
      7xl px-10 justify-evenly mx-auto items-center">
        <h3 className="absolute top-24 uppercase tracking-[20px] text-gray-500 text-2xl">
            About
        </h3>

        <motion.img
      
          initial={{
              x:-200,
          }}
          transition={{
            duration:1.2,
          }}
          whileInView={{x: 0}}
      
          src={aboutPic}
         
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably due to the location of your image.
According to your specified path, your image should be in the same folder as your 'About' component. Check your image location and path.
Note that in default image imports you can't use direct path for images stored in public folder as in urls.

Instead, you have to locate it like any exported component.
If you are in 'pages' folder and the 'images' folder is in 'public' for example:

```
import aboutPic from '../public/images/wed.jpg'
```

or

```
<img src='/images/wed.jpg'/>
```

Comment: I ended up changing my src portion to this which seemed to work: src={aboutPic.src}.   I am not sure if this is the right way but I am going to continue to test it out on other components and see if I run into any problems.

Comment: Actually, this is stated in the documentation and should compensate for using the whole image path. It should be fine